# HTML, prevent click of <a href = "#"> from altering URI

Tags: html

In HTML `<a>` tags, when you have an `href = "#"`, is there some way to *not* have the `#` appear in the URI after the `href="#"` link is clicked?

I would like to do this *without* using a bunch of CSS to make something look like a link using stuff like `cursor: pointer`, etc.

Example code -

```
<a href="#">Click your way to nothing!</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider making your link actually point to something so that it works if the user right clicks and chooses open in new tab. Then your handler can handle just the normal click, and do something else instead (and call event.preventDefault so link is not followed)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
   $('a[href="#"]').click(function() { return false; });
```

Comment: This is the correct approach, except that the OP must already be handling the click somewhere else. The key is that the OP needs to return false from the handler (or call `e.preventDefault()`)

Comment: +1 for the right way - as Juan said - if you **really want** to stick with this solution. I find it a bit user-unfriendly because it does not allow middle-mouse button clicks or *Open in new tab* functionality.